# How to use a javascript file in options.html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have trouble adding a personal javascript file in my option.html for my google-chrome extension.

I've added this line to my options.html:

```
<script type="text/javasctipt" src="/js/content/toto.js"></script>
```

And the object $.toto, described in this file is unreachable.

I would like to know if it's possible to add a personal js file and how or if you have to do everything in the options.js ?

Thank in advance for your answers.

Here is a part of the code as the project is already large:

options.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/sprintf-0.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shared/constant.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/shared/storage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javasctipt" src="/js/content/toto.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/content/messages.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/content/debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/content/form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/content/base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/content/options.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

options.js:

```
$.options = $.extend({}, $.base, {
    ready: function() {

       // onMessage                                                                             
       chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(this.onMessage);

       // init events                                                                           
       $("#logout_btn").live("click",function() {
           $.options.logout();
       });

       // init ui                                                                               
       $.toto.initialize();
       this.displayCorrectContext();
       this.initMailPrescrip();
    }
});
```

toto.js:

```
$.toto = $.extend({}, $.base, {

    TAG: "MESSAGES",

    ready: function() {
        $("[title-message]").each(function() {
            var txt = chrome.i18n.getMessage($(this).attr("title-message"));
            $(this).attr('title', txt);
        });
        $("[data-message]").each(function() {
            var txt = chrome.i18n.getMessage($(this).attr("data-message"));
            $(this).html(txt);
        });

    },

    log: function(message) {
        $.base.log($.messages.TAG,message);
    }

});
```

Comment: You do have jQuery loaded right??? The `$` is most likely (not always but usually) a jQuery reference. If the `toto.js` file contains and object that extends the jQuery object, then jQuery must be loaded prior to adding the tag above.

Comment: JQuery is loaded, and some other objects are already loaded that do exactly the same thing, the problem seems to be when loading the file toto.js because I don't see it in my debug console ("source" tab)

Answer (score 1):

Use .ready event like this.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // jquery function code

 });
```

Comment: I said i tried... And I don't want to add the options.js... Have you even read the topic?

Comment: @Manny42 if you call any javascript function inside options.phtml then you have to write them inside .ready event.

Comment: you mean if i have 3 tabs in my options.html page i do a 2000+ line options.js file ?

Comment: @Manny42 no. you add only initiate code inside .ready event but you want to add external js file for your functionality in options.html.

Comment: @Bharat_Chodvadiya And we come back to my question, I added my file in options.html and initialization function in options.js and the object remains not loaded...

Comment: @Manny42 sometime jquery functon directly not work so we want to add inside .ready event. so use $.toto initialization code inside .ready event.

Comment: As i said in my previous comment i already added initialization code in my options.js, did you get that it's in google-chrome-extension context? When i load the page, and take a look at my debug console, in the "sources" tab, the file is not loaded

Comment: @Manny42 where you add options.js in options.html. here only toto.js.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest.json, try adding it in the "scripts" line, like so:

```
"app": {
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["exampleReference1.js", "exampleReference2.js", "toto.js"],
  "transient": true
  }
},
```

Hope it works.